# Поворот объекта по оси Z unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, rotate

мне нужно что бы когда у персонажа количество xp == 0, то поворачивать игрока на 90 единиц по оси Z(В Rotate);

Игра в 2d;
Вот код

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name.Equals("Zombie"))
    {
        xp -= 20;
        if(xp == 0)
        {



            if(Z == 90)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject, 0f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Между скобочек впиши `transform.Rotate(0,0,90,Space.Self);`
Совет, не используй просто равно, если уверен, что хп не упадет ниже нуля

Comment: Спасибо, а как добавить плавности падения?